# Codeigniter: Looking for an explanation of email->set_newline(..) functionality

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I am currently developing a website with the help of **codeigniter** and the **ion auth** library.

I am trying to use ion auth's standard functionality to reset a users password.

In the library there are 2 functions:

- `forgotten_password($identity)`
- `forgotten_password_complete($code)`

Both functions (in case validation goes through) send an email to the user. The functions themselves work, but the emails i receive are broken. The emails header is displayed as a part of the emails body. This is how a broken email looks:

```
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2011 23:36:32 +0100

From: "Example.com" <admin@example.com>

Reply-To: "admin@example.com" <admin@example.com>

X-Sender: admin@example.com

X-Mailer: CodeIgniter

X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

Message-ID: <4ec6ddf0d26a3@example.com>

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_4ec6ddf0d26b9"






This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

Your email application may not support this format.



--B_ALT_4ec6ddf0d26b9

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit



New Password for test_user



Your password has been reset to: 0774b65f5e





--B_ALT_4ec6ddf0d26b9

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



<html>
<body>
    <h1>New Password for test_user</h1>
=09
    <p>Your password has been reset to: 0774b65f5e</p>
</body>
</html>



--B_ALT_4ec6ddf0d26b9--
```

However I was able to track down the line which is causing the trouble:

`$this->ci->email->set_newline("\r\n");`

When I comment out this line (in both functions mentioned above), the emails I receive when I reset a users password are fine.

Can someone explain to me the purpose of this line and wether or not it is a good idea to solve this problem by just commenting the line out.

I also found 2 questions

- [Problem sending email with Codeigniter - Headers sent in the message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627022/problem-sending-email-with-codeigniter-headers-sent-in-the-message-body)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740672/mime-format-email-breaking-sporadically-in-hotmail-php-codeigniter

referring to the same or at least a similar problem. As they are fairly old and haven't been answered yet, I created a new one. Hope no one minds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different operating systems use different characters to determine a new line (the place at which a line breaks to the next line.) In HTML, the equivalent is the `<br>` tag. Some (old? Mac) traditionally use `\r`, some (Unix) traditionally use `\n`, and others (Windows) traditionally use both (`\r\n`).

Codeigniter defaults to `\n` (see [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)), but the writer of ion auth overrode that to use `\r\n`, which is the [standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt).

So, the program parsing the email headers (which at my best guess is *nix-based) sees the non-Unix-standard `\r\n` line and starts spitting the headers out as part of the body.

To the best of my knowledge, you'll get by fine with just `\n`, which is why Codeigniter defaults to it. Every instance I've seen of people with troubles have been people using `\r\n` and getting the same problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

In CI, that setting defaults to `'\n'` when you comment that line out. The setting depends on the mail server that's being used by PHP. Sometimes postfix and some other servers will replace `\r\n` with `\r\r\n` causing errors, so in these cases it's best to just use `\n`, since the standard (RFC 822) requires `\r\n`.